# Protect Downloadable Files on server?

Tags: php, apache

like if some attempts to download a files .zips 
eg. http://usb-drive/src/Members.jpg

i don't want to bother with this AuthType Basic using apache or the PHP version..

```
<Directory "/src/Members.jpg">
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName darkness
 AuthUserFile /usr/www/
 AuthGroupFile /usr/www/
 require valid-user
</Directory>
```

then pop up login box appears….Authentication required!

i just want to direct them away to a php page instead, and handle all auth stuff via PHP
can the apache rewrite mod directives do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is the function you need, you can then do something like:

```
    <?php
$file = 'thefile.zip';

if ( permissionCheck() === true) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'You do not have permission to view this file';
}
```

You can then keep the files outside the public webroot, so they can't be accessed directly and just read them out with PHP when you want to expose them.